How to access Instagram insights including "recommend on Facebook" metrics?
I can retrieve insights for posts made directly on Instagram, but I face an issue with combined insights for posts shared on both Instagram and Facebook.
Here's the scenario: When I post a reel on Instagram and enable the option to automatically share it on Facebook, the combined views shown on Instagram reflect views from both platforms. For example, if the reel generates 10,000 views on Instagram and an additional 5,000 views on Facebook, Instagram's app displays a total of 15,000 views. However, when I call the API (GET /{ig-media-id}/insights), it only returns the 10,000 views from Instagram, excluding the 5,000 views from Facebook.
I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out how to obtain the combined insights (similar to the view shown in Instagram's app) through the API but have had no luck. I am aware that this is possible since I've seen analytics platforms display the combined numbers in their reports.
What I've Tried:

Using the Instagram Graph API endpoint GET /{ig-media-id}/insights to retrieve insights, but it only returns Instagram-specific data.
Searching through Facebook Graph API documentation for a way to aggregate insights from both platforms.
Experimenting with various metrics and parameters to ensure no data is left out.
Attempting to get insights from the Facebook page itself, but these always return empty since the page isn't being used directly.

Is there a specific API endpoint or method to retrieve the combined insights for Instagram posts shared on both Instagram and Facebook? How can I get the same combined views data that Instagram displays within its app?


